# What is the color theme used in the VS Code February 2018 release note screenshot

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been searching for the VS code color theme as shown in the GIF below with no luck. Can anyone help me?

[image: Screenshot from VS Code February 2018 release note]

Comment: Looks somewhat like https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zhuangtongfa.Material-theme

Comment: @Alex Not quite. Try to look closely with the following link: https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/updates/1_21/window-dnd-files.gif

One Dark Pro font color is abit dull as compared to the one in the screenshot

Comment: Maybe some fork with brighter colors, otherwise, looks kind of similar to me.

Answer (score 0):

This release came out with few **[`removal of old colors`](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_21#_new-theme-colors-and-removal-of-old-colors)** and some new changes have been added which you can check here

The border color of editor highlights can now also be freely chosen:

- **editor.selectionHighlightBorder:** Border color for regions with the same content as the selection.
- **editor.wordHighlightBorder:** Border color of a symbol during read-access, for example when reading a variable.
- **editor.wordHighlightStrongBorder:** Border color of a symbol during write-access, for example when writing to a variable.
- **editor.findMatchBorder:** Border color of the current search match.
  editor.findMatchHighlightBorder: Border color of the other search matches.
- **editor.findRangeHighlightBorder:** Border color the range limiting the search (Enable 'Find in Selection' in the find widget).
- **editor.rangeHighlightBorder:** Background color of the border around highlighted ranges.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. To be specific, I was looking for the syntax coloring for the typescript coding that the author is using in the screenshot.